# Particular limit calculation

Tags: limits, logarithms, asymptotics

How can we prove that

$$\lim_{j \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=2}^{j}\lceil \log(i) \rceil}{\sum_{i=2}^{j-1}\lceil \log(i) \rceil} = 1$$

where $\log$ is the binary log?

Thank you

Comment: Hint: This is $1+\lim_{j \to \infty} \dfrac{\lceil \log(j) \rceil}{\sum_{i=2}^{j-1}\lceil \log(i) \rceil} $.

Comment: Thanks for your hint :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{\sum_{i=2}^{j}\lceil \log(i) \rceil}{\sum_{i=2}^{j-1}\lceil \log(i) \rceil}=1+\frac{\lceil \log(j) \rceil}{\sum_{i=2}^{j-1}\lceil \log(i) \rceil}, $$
so you need to show that the final term on the right goes to zero.

When $2^{n-1}<j\le 2^n$, the numerator equals $n$, while at least $2^{n-2}$ terms in the denominator are $n-2$ or $n-1$. More precisely,
$$\sum_{i=2}^{j-1}\lceil \log(i) \rceil
\ge \sum_{i=2^{n-2}+1}^{2^{n-1}}\lceil \log(i) \rceil
= \sum_{i=2^{n-2}+1}^{2^{n-1}}(n-1)=2^{n-1}(n-1),$$
so that $$\frac{\lceil \log(j) \rceil}{\sum_{i=2}^{j-1}\lceil \log(i) \rceil}\le\frac{n}{2^{n-1}(n-1)},$$
and we're done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by "the rest is plain sailing"?

Comment: Now, I am not sure that $\frac{\lceil \log(j) \rceil}{\sum_{i=2}^{j-1}\lceil \log(i) \rceil}$ tends to $0$.

Comment: I think you want to say that we can lower bound the denominator by $j-2$.

Comment: “Plain sailing” is a metaphor meaning easy, no hidden dangers. But you're right, I was too quick anyhow. Hang on, I'll fix it …

Comment: I hope it's correct now. It is (and was) at least *philosophically* correct, though some detail was wrong. I'm off to the movies soon, hope you can fix any remaining mistakes on your own.

Comment: The argument seems correct. Thank you again :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

For $j=8$, 
$$1+\frac{3}{1+2+2}<1+\frac3{2\cdot2}$$
For $j=16$, 
$$1+\frac{4}{1+2+2+3+3+3+3}<1+\frac4{3\cdot2^2}$$
For $j=32$, 
$$1+\frac{5}{1+2+2+3+3+3+3+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4}<1+\frac5{4\cdot2^3}$$

You get the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Stirling's approximation:
$$n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n,$$
and l'Hopital's rule we get:
$$L=\lim_\limits{j\to\infty} \frac{\log_2 j!}{\log_2 (j-1)!}=\lim_\limits{j\to\infty} \frac{j\log_2 j-(\log_2 e)j+O(\log_2 j)}{(j-1)\log_2 (j-1)-(\log_2 e)(j-1)+O(\log_2 (j-1))}=\cdots=\frac{\frac{1}{j\ln 2}+O(-\frac{1}{j^2 \ln 2})}{\frac{1}{(j-1)\ln 2}+O(-\frac{1}{(j-1)^2 \ln 2})}=1.$$